# Does the expansion of $\sin x$ contradict the normal formula $\sin x = \frac{\text{Perpendicular}}{\text{Hypotenuse}}$?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, trigonometric-series

Lets say I have a right angled triangle with sides $3, 4$ and $5$ units. They form a perfect Pythagorean triplet. One of the angles in the triangle, say $\alpha$ must have the following condition:

$$\sin\alpha=\frac35$$

On the other hand, the [expansion of the $\sin$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine#Series_definition) shall never give such a definite answer.

Do they contradict? Or am I missing something?

If they contradict, which one is correct (*more correct*)?

Comment: Why do you think that expansion do not give a definite answer?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, an infinite series will sum exactly to the value you are looking for, *when you put in the $\alpha=\arcsin\frac35$ value, which is not a very nice number*. It works in the forward direction ($\sin\alpha$ from $\alpha$, not the other way around). For the inverse function, use an expansion of $\arcsin x$.

You are not actually computing $\sin\alpha$ from $\alpha$. You are just rescaling the value that *already is* propotional to $\sin\alpha$ by definition. You have the sine, but you have no idea what the angle is, so calculation of $\sin\alpha$ was never actually performed.

---

$\sin\alpha$ is a function that takes a number $\alpha$ and gives you back $\sin\alpha$. The infinite series that you found is one of the ways to do that.

You don't actually know $\alpha$ in your triangle. You just *marked* the angle and figured out from the triangle's geometry what $\sin\alpha$ is. This means you never actually computed the function by giving it a known value.

In short - now you know $\sin\alpha$ but don't know $\alpha$. You *could* get $\alpha$ from this, if you used the inverse function of $\sin$: $\alpha=\arcsin\frac{3}{5}$. So your problem is *not* how to calculate the $\sin\alpha$ from $\alpha$ but exactly the inverse problem: how to get $\alpha$ from $\sin\alpha$. And that's a different thing.

You can compute the function $\alpha=\arcsin x$ with a series too. For instance, check out the infinite series here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arcsin#Infinite_series

To summarize: computing the function $\sin\alpha$ for a general value of $\alpha$ is not something you can do with elementary functions (exceptions are the "nice" angles with known values). Otherwise you wouldn't need a calculator for that! You can compute the values using infinite series, or some other technique. Your division didn't actually compute the function, it just told you the value for *some* angle.

Note that once you have $\sin\alpha$, you can get other trigonometric functions of the same angle easily from formulas like $\cos\alpha=\sqrt{1-\sin^2\alpha}$ and $\tan\alpha=\frac{\sin\alpha}{\cos\alpha}$. But that's another story...

Comment: Didn't understand it properly. I have just passed high-school. Can you please write in a bit more non-technical language?

Comment: Expanded the answer. Better?

Comment: Thank you so much. That was brilliant! I am just starting at complex mathematics so I don't have a hands on the proper ways of assessing problems like this. Marking the question as solved...